# Enlightenment E19 Screen Magnifier

Tags: ubuntu, gui, enlightenment

I'm looking for a solution for accessibility in the Enlightenment E19 WM. I am using Bodhi Linux 3.0.0, returning from a long hiatus of Linux. Last time I used Linux in a desktop environment was Ubuntu in 2009 and at that time I seem to remember a full screen zoom feature through Compiz-Fusion or something to that effect. I have searched extensively and it seems that the accessibility options in Ubuntu have been push aside in recent years. Since Bodhi Linux is based on Ubuntu **I am wondering if there are others out there who have found alternatives to the full screen magnifier that was once bundled with Ubuntu?**

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading xzoom.  It's in the repositories and is lighter on your system than kmag.

Comment: It would be good to add a link to xzoom's home or downloading page.